# Pass Joomla Plugin Version to ini file

Tags: plugins, joomla

I have a simple Joomla plugin with several ini translation files.
In this files I have a tag that indicates my plugin version (PLG_VERSION="Plugin Version x.x.x"), but when I make an update to my plugin and I change the plugin version (in xml file) I have to edit every translation ini files and change my PLG_VERSION tag to inform the new plugin version. Is there a way to update automatically the PLG_VERSION tag by getting XML Version tag?
I read this [How to get component version from Joomla?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293108/how-to-get-component-version-from-joomla) but I could not pass the version value to ini file.
How can I achieve it?
Use Joomla 3.x

Regards

Comment: There must be a plugin xml file in the plugin folder, you need to specify version in this xml file and you should use this version using mentioned link in your question. See xml file structure [here](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already a working system plugin, the version tag is inserted in xml file and I can get the version with the mentioned code. What I can´t get is to pass that value to language ini file.

Comment: You should Use like: `LANGUAGE_TAG="Version is %s"` in .ini file and when you echo it you must Use `echo JText::_("LANGUAGE_TAG,$version");` Value of `$version` can be fetched as you are able to do this.

Comment: Thanks. In plugin xml file I have `<description>PLG_VERSION</description>`. PLG_VERSION is the tag that I have in translation files and it there that I want to insert the plugin version. How can I pass it to there?

Comment: Ohk, Then you have to edit ini files.

Comment: There is no way to pass it to there?